# Stop Ubuntu Changing UEFI boot order

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

After I install Ubuntu on my machine that has both ubuntu and windows, when I boot Ubuntu, every single time I have to go change the UEFI boot order back to what it was, because Ubuntu changes it every time I boot, and it's driving me crazy. I do not mean changing the GRUB bootloader order, I mean the boot order that is set in the motherboard UEFI settings.

Edit:
I am on a machine that has 22.04 LTS, but I have had this problem with every single version of Ubuntu that I have installed for the past several years, which is why I had left the specific version unstated. It is not version specific.

What I need is a way to prevent Ubuntu/grub from changing grub to be the first bootloader choice in the BIOS every single time I boot with grub into Ubuntu. Every time I boot Ubuntu, I need to enter my BIOS and change the boot order back to what I want it to be, where grub is not the first option. My motherboard is an ASUS MAXIMUS Formula VII, and I haven't changed any settings in windows that might be sync'd over. When I boot windows after making the windows bootloader the first choice, the boot order doesn't change, including if the grub bootloader is the first choice. But when I boot with grub into Ubuntu, the boot order changes to put grub as first in the boot order.

Comment: You've not provided any Ubuntu product/release details; are we to guess?  I've not experienced what you describe, but then again my Ubuntu product & release may differ to your *unstated* OS/release.

Comment: What brand/model system? Normally both Windows & Ubuntu/grub change boot order on new install, but not otherwise. You can set boot order with efibootmgr. A few brands like HP seem to only want Windows as first in boot order and ignore efibootmgr changes. Did you also change Windows BCD to have Ubuntu first? Some sync BCD with UEFI.